# how do I "group" data using handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I wanna use handlebars to display some records but the results needs to be grouped.

sample data:

```
{"data":[
  { "sn":"lecture","areasn":"3"},
  { "sn":"lab","areasn":"1"},
  { "sn":"lecture","areasn":"2"},
  { "sn":"field","areasn":"3"},
  { "sn":"lab","areasn":"1"},
  { "sn":"exam","areasn":"2"}
]}
```

I want the display to be something like:

```
field
    3
exam
    2
lab
    1
    1
lecture
    2
    3
```

so basically the data is grouped.

Any ideas on how this can be done? Thanks

Comment: You don't; you do the data massaging in JavaScript before passing it into Handlebars.

Comment: You can `registerHelper` to do that.